# Querying a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am still very new to  Pandas and hence this might be very silly.I have Pandas data frame as follows:

```
>>> data_frame
     median quarter status  change
0     240   2015-1     BV     NaN
1     300   2015-2     BV    0.25
2     300   2015-1   CORR    0.00
3     240   2015-2   CORR   -0.20
```

Now i need only the quarter 2015-2,so i perform the query

```
>>> data_frame.query('quarter == "2015-2"')
     median quarter status  change
 1     300  2015-2     BV    0.25
 2     240  2015-2   CORR   -0.20
```

That works fine.However if I need to search via a variable name,it does not work.

```
>>> completed_quarter = '2015-2'
>>> data_frame.query('quarter == "completed_quarter"')
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [median, quarter, status, change]
Index: []
```

I tried a few other combinations with single quotes, no quotes etc but nothing works.What am I doing wrong ? Is there any other way in Pandas through which I can accomplish the same thing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying using this:

```
>>> completed_quarter = '2015-2'
>>> data_frame.query('quarter == "{}"'.format(completed_quarter))
```

At the moment you are searching for a quarter that equals "completed_quarter" rather than the value of the `completed_quarter` variable. Using string [format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) method will replace the value in braces with the variable value.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the value of the variable like this

```
completed_quarter = '2015-2'
data_frame.query('quarter == @completed_quarter')
```

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html